# Where am I going wrong with this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Been using jQuery for a little while but no expert.
I have a number of elements identified by a class. These are put into an array thus:

```
var myArray = $(".clientprofilequestionwrapper");
```

I then loop through this array thus:

```
$(myArray).each(function () {
```

So far so good. All is working.

Now the problem.
Each of the objects in the array is as follows:

```html
    <div class="clientprofilequestionwrapper" data-sg-question-id="3109" data-sg-question-last="true" data-sg-question-type="ST">
        <span class="sg-quest-text">Stu ST question test</span>
        <div class="command-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left command-button-wrapper">
                <a class="select" data-sg-outcome-id="123" data-sg-outcome-pass="true" href="#" id="3109Yes" title="Yes">
                    <div class="ST text-original margin-bottom-10px round-radius outer-button-div selected">
                        <div class="text-original topclear inner-button-div">Yes</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left command-button-wrapper">
                <a class="select" data-sg-outcome-id="123" data-sg-outcome-pass="true" href="#" id="3109No" title="No">
                    <div class="ST text-original margin-bottom-10px round-radius outer-button-div">
                        <div class="text-original topclear inner-button-div">No</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically this represents 2 buttons (command-button-wrapper) as 1 part of a questionnaire (so there are multiple divs with class clientprofilequestionwrapper, each representing a question).

So I want to get the button which is selected.

Note: $(this) represents the div element with the class "clientprofilequestionwrapper".

If I do an alert on $(this).find(".selected") it comes up with "object object" which means it has found something.

Similarly if I do $(this).find(".selected").parent() it comes up with "object object" which I believe is the  tag above it.

I believe I'm in the right place in the DOM.

But when I go to get the title using $(this).find(".selected").parent().attr("title") I get undefined.

So can somebody point out where my failure in jQuery understanding is please.

This is legacy code and I know it's not done very elegantly but I'm hoping for a quick fix to this "live issue" rather than a total re-write!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186324/discussion-on-question-by-stuart-mccallum-where-am-i-going-wrong-with-this-jquer).

Comment: SOLUTION: there is no answer to this sadly.What I did was move the dynamic adding of the class selected from the problem div element to the parent a element.Worked first time.If anybody can reason as to why this worked then this will help others who may find this question.Working selector now reads $(this).find("a.selected").first().attr("title")